# Form Preventdefault not working, redirecting to post url

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot application. I have a favorite button in which the button image changes depending on if the user has Favorited the item.

Originally I had it working by accepting a form post request, updating the DB, and sending a redirect back to the Referer, but this was reloading the page every time, so I thought I would try using jQuery Ajax.

Controller.java:

```
//     //Favorite/Unfavorite existing recipes
//    @RequestMapping(value = "/recipes/{id}/favorite", method = RequestMethod.POST)
//    public String favoriteRecipe(@PathVariable Long id, Model model, HttpServletRequest request, Authentication
//            authentication) {
//
//        User user = userService.findByUsername(authentication.getName());
//        model.addAttribute("user", user);
//        Recipe recipe = recipeService.findById(id);
//
//        userService.toggleFavorite(user, recipe);
//
//        userService.save(user);
//
//        return "redirect:" + request.getHeader("Referer");
//    }

    // Favorite/Unfavorite existing recipes
    @PostMapping("/recipes/{id}/favorite")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void favoriteRecipe(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model, Authentication authentication) {
        User user = userService.findByUsername(authentication.getName());
        //model.addAttribute("user", user);
        Recipe recipe = recipeService.findById(id);

        userService.toggleFavorite(user, recipe);

        userService.save(user);

        //return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

index.html:

```
<a th:href="@{|/details/${recipe.id}|}">
   <div class="grid-70">
     <p>
       <form id="test" th:action="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}/favorite|}" method="post" style="display:inline">
          <button type="submit" id="favorite-button-index">
             <img th:src="${recipe.userFavorites.contains(#authentication.name)} ? @{/assets/images/favorited.svg} : @{/assets/images/favorite.svg}"
                                         style="height: 12px;">
           </button>
       </form>
       <span th:text="${recipe.name}"> </span>

      </p>
    </div>
 </a>
```

app.js:

```
$('#test').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#favorite-button-detail').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var recipeID = [[${recipe.id}]];
        var url = "/recipes/" + recipeID + "/favorite";

        $.post(url, function(data) {
            alert(data)
        });
    })
})
```

This is the way I tried implementing in my app.js. I have confirmed the data is being updated in the DB, but I am unable to stop the redirect to the POST url. The issue seems to be coming from the th:action in the form.

I've looked through a lot other questions/examples on this and haven't been able to figure out why it is happening. I've tried preventdefault, returning false, wrapping in a $( document ).ready().

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: owowowow you have `.submit()` inside `.submit()`. The inner one is not needed at all

Comment: when someone will click on your submit button it will submit your form. so you do not need ```$('#favorite-button-detail').submit```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not good to have two nested submits. And I'm not sure what's the idea behind wrapping `[[${recipe.id}]]` in double arrays...??

Try with:

```js
$('#test').on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(this.action, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

where `this.action` is the actual form's **action** attribute value `@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}/favorite|}` 
And you don't need any button JS stuff any more.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my issue with the redirect. Also, I accidentally typed the double arrays haha.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Roko's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383904/roko-c-buljan) answer you still have to figure out a solution to refresh your ui in order to change button image without refreshing the whole page because you are using a server-side rendering template engine.
I suggest you just change the image of the button after a successful response like this:

```
$('#test').on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(this.action, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var imageUrl = (data.favorited)?'/assets/images/favorited.svg':'/assets/images/favorite.svg'; 
        $('#favorite-button-index>img').attr('src', imageUrl);
    });
};
```

Also in this case to make `data.favorited` work you should return a data about user has favorite or not from your spring controller method. Here is a sample that returns json data so you can easily use in javascript:

```
@PostMapping("/recipes/{id}/favorite")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> favoriteRecipe(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Authentication authentication) {
    User user = userService.findByUsername(authentication.getName());

    Recipe recipe = recipeService.findById(id);
    userService.toggleFavorite(user, recipe);

    userService.save(user);

    boolean hasFavorite = recipe.userFavorites.contains(authentication.getName());

    Map<String, Object> resultJson = new HashMap<>();
    resultJson.put("favorited", hasFavorite);

    return resultJson;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the follow up response. This was going to be my next challenge. This was very informative about how I should approach this problem.